# 3D plot with date and time on diff axes (x & y) and dependent variable on Z-axis

Tags: datetime, gnuplot

I have the following input data format, as an example:

```
9/18/2015,08.00.00,101
9/18/2015,08.15.00,203
9/18/2015,08.30.00,429
. . .
9/19/2015,08.00.00,50
9/19/2015,08.15.11,77
9/19/2015,08.30.05,200
. . . 
9/20/2015,08.00.50,446
9/20/2015,08.15.00,431
9/20/2015,08.30.00,580
. . .
```

I want to generate a 3D plot (such as a wall plot) using gnuplot 5.0 where the X-Axis represents "%H.%M" for a given day, the Y-Axis represents a unique date (%m/%d) for all the %H:%M for that day, and the Z-Axis represents an integer value (the dependent variable).

The following code is not working for me as I'm getting a repeated date on the Y-Axis (like 09/18), and the Z-axis values appear to be diagonally plotted across the X-Y axes. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Code Example:

```
reset
set terminal wxt enhanced
set datafile separator ","

set xlabel "Hour"
set ylabel "Date"
set zlabel "Int"
set timefmt '%m/%d/%Y,%H.%M.%S'
set xdata time
set ydata time
set format x '%H.%M'
set format y '%m/%d'
splot 'inputfile.csv' u 3:3:11
```

3D plot datetime 2 axes:
[image]

Comment: your `using 3:3:11` option should be `using 2:1:3` to get the right axes, but it  looks like an `every` option.

Comment: Besides, `set timefmt '%H.%M.%S'` should be before `set xdata time`, and similarly for `ydata`. Hopefully, someone knows how you can mix such data formats.